# rm -irf -Irf with find

Tags: shell, find, rm, exec

why below statement do not ask for confirmation while using option i or I for rm ?

```
// pass aggregated 
find . -name $name -type d -exec rm -irf {} \;
// pass each
find . -name $name -type d -exec rm -irf {} +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-i` option asks for confirmation but the `-f` option which follows in your command overrides it, turning off the confirmation dialog.

Observe:

```
$ rm -fri file1
rm: remove regular empty file 'file1'? n
$ rm -irf file1
$
```

If the first form above, `-f` appears first and `-i` latter.  Consequently, `-i` overrides `-f` and `rm` asks for confirmation.

In the second form above, `-i` appears first and `-f` latter.  In this case, `-f` overrides and no confirmation dialog appears.

#### Documentation

From `man rm`:

> **-f, --force**
>           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
>
> **-i**
>       prompt before every removal
>
> **-I**
>   prompt  once  before  removing more than three files, or when removing recursively; less intrusive than -i, while still giving
>    protection against most mistakes

Comment: so it should be only -ir or -Ir :)  without forcing

Comment: and what would be the best way (match) to protect from harmful delete using -I or -i  and + or \; ?

Comment: @ceph3us Yes, omit the `-f`.  The option `-i` provides more protection than `-I`.  If you are using `-i`, then `find ...\;` and `find ...+` are both equally safe with the later being more computationally efficient.